# How do I invert this sparse lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, inverse, sparse-matrices

I have square matrix of size $n$ filled with the following values

$$ T(i,j) = \begin{cases} 1 & i=j \\ -1 & j=k(i) \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

where $k(i)=\{ \ldots \}$ is vector of integers, each one $k(i)<i$.

Example with $n=4$ generated from $k=\{ 0, 1, 1, 3 \}$

$$ T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Notice that for each row $i$ there is only one $-1$ at the $k(i)$ column.

Now I want to find a rule for any $n>1$ that would generate $B=$T^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 &  &  &  \\ 
   & 1 &   & \mbox{all zeros}  \\
  & \ddots & 1 & \\
  \mbox{zeros}& \mbox{or ones}& & 1 
\end{bmatrix} $$

For the example $T$  above we have

$$ B=T^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Please try to include step by step example for the $T$ value above.

Using matlab I initialize $T$ with the following code:

```
% Parent indices
k = [0,1,1,3]   % or [0,1,2,3], [0,1,1,1], [0,1,2,2], ...

% Construct adjacency matrix T
n = size(k,2);
T = eye(n);
for i=2:n
    T(i,k(i))=-1;
end
```

**Edit 1**

I tried the method of setting $(T^{-1})_{ij}=1$ if $j$ is a multiple of $k(i)$ and it didn't work. Here is the sample matlab code:

```
%Find B=inv(T)
B = eye(n);
for i=2:n
    for j=1:i-1
        for u=1:i-1
            if j==(k(i))^u
                B(i,j) = 1;
                break
            end
        end
    end
end

T=
     1     0     0     0
    -1     1     0     0
    -1     0     1     0
     0     0    -1     1

B=  
     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1
(not correct)
```

**Edit 2**
I tried the following matlab code

```
%Find B=inv(T)
B = eye(n);
for i=2:n
    for j=1:i-1
        B(i,j) = -T(i,k(i))*B(k(i),j);
    end
end
```

and it works it seems fine for cases where $k(i)<i$ (lower triangular matrix). With a little more testing I think I can award an answer.

**Edit 3**

I have settled with

```
B=eye(n);
for i=2:n,
    j=k(i);
    while j>0,
        B(i,j)=1;
        j=k(j);
    end;
end
```

based on the answer & comments by [user1551](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1551/user1551).  Here is the test code for posterity:

```
% Size
n  = 15
% k=Parent indices
k = zeros(1,n);
for i=2:n
    k(1,i) = int32(1+rand*(i-2) )
end
% Assemble T
T = eye(n);
for i=2:n
    T(i,k(i))=-1;
end

% Generate B=inv(T) with various methods

if(B*T==eye(n)) 
    disp('CORRECT')
else
    disp('FAIL')
end
```

Comment: Explicit formula: $T^{-1}\left(i,j\right)$ is $1$ if $j$ has the form $k^u\left(i\right)$ for some nonnegative integer $u$ (where $k\left(0\right) := 0$), and is $0$ otherwise. The proof is easy (just multiply the two matrices).

Comment: In your code, "k(i)^u" should be "k^u(i)", though I don't know whether whatever language you are using knows this syntax. The point is to apply u times the map k to i.

Comment: @darijgrinberg added parens for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: @ja72 Your $T$ is lower triangular and you have stated clearly that $k(i)<i$. How is it possible that $k=[0,3,2,1]$? Anyway, given a legitimate vector $k$, you can generate $B$ as follows: `B=zeros(n,n);for i=1:n,j=i;while j>0,B(i,j)=1;j=k(j);end;end`

Comment: @user1551 - You are correct. I will fix the example code. Please add your code as an answer as I like it a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T^{-1}=B$. Forward substitution gives $B_{i\ast}=e_i^T+B_{k(i)\ast}$. That is, the $i$-th row of $B$ is basically identical to the $k(i)$-th row, except that $b_{ii}$ is also equal to $1$. Put it another way,
$$
b_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if } j\in\left\{i,\,k(i),\,k^2(i),\ldots,\,k^{i-1}(i)\right\},\\
0&\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Is there a formal name for $e_i$, a vector of zeros except the _i_-th element being 1?

Comment: I tried this method (also mentioned in the comments) but it doesn't work out. See edited question for my try.

Comment: @ja72 Not one I've heard of, but $e_i$ is just the $i$-th vector in the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: More importantly the name for the subspace $n_i$ which contains all the element vectors of $\mathbb R^n$ _except_ $e_i$?

Comment: @ja72 I'm not aware of any name for that.

Comment: You comment helped me the most, so please add the algo to the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the general matrix multiplication formula:

$\left[\begin{array}{lcr}1&0&0\\a&1&0\\b&c&1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{lcr}1&0&0\\\alpha&1&0\\\beta&\gamma&1\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{lcr}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]
$
requires
$\left\{\begin{array}{c}\alpha=-a,\\\beta=-b-\alpha c,\\ \gamma=-c\end{array}\right\}$

Similar recursive formulas hold for higher-dimensional arrays.  So to figure out your $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, you need only to plug them into the formulas like this.  The fact that only one of each row will be -1, and the rest will be 0's allow for a simple formulation of your recursive formula:

$A^{-1}_{i,j}=-A_{i,k(i)}A^{-1}_{k(i),j}$

which you can start by filling out from the top.

For your example:

$T^{-1}_{21}=-T_{2,k(2)}T^{-1}_{k(1),1}=-T_{21}T^{-1}_{11}=--1\cdot 1=1$

$T^{-1}_{31}=-T_{31}T^{-1}_{11}=--1\cdot 1 = 1$

$T^{-1}_{32}=-T_{31}T^{-1}_{12}=--1\cdot 0 = 0$

$T^{-1}_{41}=-T_{43}T^{-1}_{31}=--1\cdot 1 = 1$

$T^{-1}_{42}=-T_{43}T^{-1}_{32}=--1\cdot 0 = 0$

$T^{-1}_{43}=-T_{43}T^{-1}_{33}=--1\cdot 1 = 1$

Note that at each step, you already know the value of $T^{-1}_{ij}$ by the time you need it (the first case being $T^{-1}_{11}=1$ because it's on the diagonal.

Comment: In the end I want a computer algorithm, and not something that I match coefficients by hand. Can you show and example with $n=4$ like I have in the question?

Comment: Sure, this can be programmed into a recursive computer algorithm.  Just start with the top row, and go down, and any cross-references should be resolved by the time you get there.  OK, I'll demo.

Comment: Per the example, shouldn't the rule be $A^{-1}_{i,j}=-A_{i,k(i)}A^{-1}_{k(j),j}$? you wrote $A^{-1}_{i,j}=-A_{i,k(i)}A^{-1}_{k(i),j}$. In the example you reference $k(1)$ and $k(2)$ index in the first line, but the rule only references $k(i)$.

Comment: Please correct the example. $k(1)=0$ always, and in your example you have ${T^{-1}}_{k(1),1}$ which is undefined.